# How to Use Multiple Condition in Open Formula in Pentaho Report Designer?

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

For single condition it is correct but if there is multiple condition hard to customize in open formula.
For example i want grading like A,B,C .I did such but doesn't work?

Code tried:

```
=IF([total]>90;"A";0 IF(OR([total]<80 ; [total]<=90);"B";0; IF(OR([total]<60 ; [total]<=70);"C";0; )))
```

Comment: =IF([total]>90;"A";0
IF(OR([total]<80 ; [total]<=90);"B";0;
IF(OR([total]<60 ; [total]<=70);"C";0;
)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below in the open formula section:

```
=IF([total]>90;"A";IF(OR([total]<80 ; [total]<=90);"B";"C"))
```

Since there is a nested looping condition you would need to place the inner condition inside the ELSE part of the Outer Condition.

Also i assume you need to display the grade against the marks scored by a student. So You can take a "Label" into the details section of the report. Open the **Attribute** section of the label and inside the **value** part, use the above formula. Check the image below:*(highlighted)* 
[image]

Hope it helps :)